# Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit not found

Tags: mysql

Use `systemctl start mysqld` to start mysql service, failed error:
Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit not found.
Use `journalctl -xe` to see details log, show that: 
fatal: unable to use my own hostname

so how to solve it, i find some solutions, but can not solve it.

Comment: it would be related to the wrong config, try to find out the cause in error logs...

Comment: @Girish below is logs:[root@10 ~]# journalctl -xe
 postfix/pickup[11470]: fatal: unable to use my own hostname
 postfix/master[1059]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup pid 11470 e
 postfix/master[1059]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup: bad command startu
 postfix/pickup[11473]: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 10.211.55.19

Comment: what is your ubuntu version?

Comment: Is this a new installation or existing installation? Check path, usually /usr/locl/mysql/bin and check if 'mysql' is there.

Answer (score 6):

If on Ubuntu try without the 'd'

```
systemctl start mysql
```